# Cannot find my database in SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I re-installed visual studio 2017 on my machine and when I opened my project, I did not see my project database under SQL Server Object Explorer. However, prior to uninstalling, it was showing the database.

In my appsettings.json file, I have the follwing connection:

{

```
  "ConnectionStrings":{ 
    "Default": "Server=(Localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Vega; Integrated Security=SSPI" 
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Hence, what I did was add a connection under Server Explorer -> Data Connection like this:

[image]

When I type in my database name, I get the error shown in the image. How can I bring back my database?

Here's my SQL Server Object Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Did you make a backup before you started messing around with the installation of sql server? Did you uninstall first and then install, or install over the top?

Comment: Under "services" (windows search: services), find your SQL server process "SQL Server (MSSQLLocalDB)" and make sure it is running. Next step depends on if it is running or not.

Comment: It's running. Please see my database explorer image above.

Comment: @tgolisch I don't think this would be under services considering it's "localdb".

Comment: @bangbang Do you have SQL Server authentication mode turned on? If so, have you tried logging in using the `sa` account?

Comment: Any chance you moved the `Vega` database (file) or changed permission on that folder (hdd), bitlocker, etc.? Please confirm the mdf file is still where you left it and it is not left open by another process.

Comment: I dont know how to check if sql server authentication is turned on in visual studio and I am not sure about the mdf file. Guys am pretty new to this.

Comment: @bangbang From the looks of your screenshot, it seems that you're able to connect to localdb at least, or is that a screenshot from before? if so, try enabling `sa`. Right click the server, open a new query and type: `alter login sa enable; go; alter login sa with password='you_new_sa_password';go;`. Then login using `sa`.

Comment: The screenshot if from this project. I ran the queries you mentioned. Now, where do I login?

Comment: Change your connection string from windows authentication to sql server authentication

Comment: Already tried that. I am still not seeing my db